# Change LOCAL_ID Dynamically for i18n in Angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, locale, french

I am building a multilingual app and I am using the *Translations at compile-time*
approach provided by Angular i18n.
I am building my App in French, so I must use

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr" }
```

to provide the LOCALE_ID in French so,Pipes and Dates would be in the provided lang.
I have set the translation configuration in the *angular.json* file as shown below:

```
...
 "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "fr",
    "locales": {
      "ar": "src/locale/messages.ar.xlf",
      "en": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf"
    }
  }
```

Issue: When I generate translation files and build the project using the --localize option I get everything fine concerning routes, translated texts etc ... The issue is in the LOCALE_ID which should be in the targeted language BUT it's always in *French* because I'm setting it in the App.module.ts* as mentioned above.
For example: When I open a Date picker, I always get t in French.

I know that this behavior is a consequent of setting the LOCALE_ID manually, so even if I was browsing the built APP in English or Arabic, the LOCALE_ID is always overridden.
That's the idea of my question:
How to set LOCALE_ID depending on the provided lang from *angular.json*?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to have my App in French by default, I was setting the LOCALE_ID manually in the **app/module.ts**:

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr" }
```

And I shouldn't do so, because later on, the APP will not get benefit from the locales provided in **angular.json** (they will be overridden).
Actually, everything works perfect after the build (I have removed the code above from **app/module.ts**).

As a result, I get three versions of the App (ar, en and fr) which work perfectly.